# Modifying a Bootstrap theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, themes

I'm trying to modify a theme for Bootstrap called 'Agency'. The specific problem I'm having is that I want the circular logo (top right) to respond and shrink as screen shrinks. I have tried adding the img-responsive class tag to the image but this didn't work. I wonder if the previous a class is overriding the img-responsive class?

Here's the html for the navigation section...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Howard &amp; Sturt | Carpentry &amp; Building | Dorking, Surrey</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top" class="index">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img src="img/howard-sturt-logo.png" width="142" height="142" alt="Logo"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Our work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

The page is loaded here (to view CSS)...

http://alexch.net/howardandsturt/

Answer (score 0):

The image is not big enough in width and height so it wont adapt as the screen shrinks. As a test, try making the image size bigger and adding the bootstrap `class="img-responsive"`class and youll see that it works.

What you could do is at a specific breakpoint add 100% height to the image element as it will fit its parent which is the navbar-brand at 50px, then override the padding accordingly. And then at your desktop breakpoint take off this 100% height and set it to auto to contain the element.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```